# Simple hello world program in java with Eclipse

Tags: java

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
public class HelloProgram extends GraphicsProgram {
   public void run() {
      add(new GLabel("hello, world"), 100, 75);
   }
}
```

I learned this code on http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/121/materials/artsciencejava.pdf page 23. However , when I run it in Eclipse , it shows many errors. It said I can't import cam.graphics.* and so on. Can anyone tell me what to do ?  Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: you need to download acm jar and put it into eclipse buildpath in compile-time libraries

Comment: Thank you Allan!! I'm an immigration from China,still taking basic English class in the school. I'm not only can learn coding here but also English skill~~~~~  Interesting and thanks again

Answer (score 4):

You haven't added the appropriate external libraries to Eclipse's build path. Do you have the acm jar files? If so, right click on your project and add the library paths to your build path.

[image]

After clicking on Build Path, then click on `Add External Archives...`

Note, I've made this answer a Community Wiki so that I won't benefit from up-votes and so all can edit and improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Download the java library that he is using here:

http://jtf.acm.org/acm.jar

Then add the library to your build path as described here:

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the acm package of the [JTF project](http://jtf.acm.org/index.html) - click [here](http://jtf.acm.org/acm.jar) for the download.
2. Save `acm.jar` into a folder on your computer (perhaps one near your project files)
3. In Eclipse, right-click on your project: *Build Path > Configure Build Path > Libraries > Add External Jars* then select the jar file you just downloaded

Comment: Thank you very much!!!  I was working this problem hardly last night , when I wake up in the morning , check stack overflow ,I solved it in 3 minutes easily !!!!